# Remove 1px line in navigation bar of a split view controller

Tags: swift, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

I'm trying to remove a the line between the navigation bar and the content.

What I've tried so far:

```
    navigationBar.setValue(true, forKey: "hidesShadow")
    navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
    navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

I'm doing this on my controller for the masterVC.

I've tried

```
    splitViewController.viewControllers.first?.shadowImage = UIImage()
    splitViewController.viewControllers.first?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

Both I not have success.

I think that I'm not getting the right reference for my navigationBar.
But I'm pretty sure that I in the right controller.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the appearance proxy?

Comment: @matt I don't know what appearance proxy is

Comment: Why not find out? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Appearance+proxy+iOS+navigation+bar

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the view controller where you want to remove the line:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: I've tried it on the master view controller and didn't worked